# AngularJS checkboxes checking from pivot table?

Tags: angularjs, checklist-model

I created the following with the plugin: http://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/

```
<section ng-repeat="owner in lord.owners">

    <form ng-submit="foobar(owner)" name="update_location_form">

    <input type="text" ng-model="owner.name">

    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="sheep in sheeps">
            <input checklist-model="owner.sheeps" checklist-value="sheep.id" type="checkbox"> 
            <label class="checkbox">{{ sheep.name }}</label>
        </li>
    </ul>    

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>    

    </form>

</section>
```

All sheeps are shown in the list. And saving to my pivot table (manytomany-relation) also works.

But when I refresh the page, all checks are gone of course. How can I access them?

They're stored in:

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: "Obama",
    farms: [
        {
            id: 10,
            name: "VirtualFarm",
            sheeps: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    name: "Foo",
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    name: "Bar",
                },
                {
                    id: 10,
                    name: "Cow",
                },
                {
                    id: 13,
                    name: "Hey",
                },
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

But I really have now clue how I can check the checkboxes by default that are in the Pivot table.

Someone?

Comment: so you're saving the checkboxes to a pivot table and that is working? I am not familiar with pivot, but is there some sort of function you can call to GET the data rather than SET? It sounds like you need to GET the pivot table data and on success render your checks

Comment: @ronnie in the json example you can see what i'm getting > "sheeps" is the pivot part

Comment: I would say first try to define a `ng-model` on an `chechbox`, and when you get your data back, after refresh etc. set it to `true or false`. That way you'll be able to see your selection that you have made before refreshing.

Comment: ok, got it. so what part of the checklist-model plugin equates a check mark to being checked? In regular angular you'd use the ng-checked attribute.

Comment: @NemanjaMilosavljevic I say refresh, but mean every time I load that page with the model.
I don't know how to check it with the data I have from the pivot..

Comment: you need to save a value to pivot that has the value of the checkbox..value meaning checked or unchecked

Comment: if it's in the pivot, then its true always. isn't there something like: ```<input type=checkbox ng-if={checked: (owner.farms.sheeps - array-check-or-something-else)}```

Answer (score 0):

The `checklist-model` directive automatically checks the appropriate checkboxes based on the value of the `checklist-model`. You don't have to do anything else, your code looks fine. But ...

First of all, I suspect that `owner in lord.owners` must be something like `owner in x.farms` where x is the object that you pasted above.

And this is on the client side and even though you check this boxes, you still need to save them on the server-side. On a refresh, every data not persisted on the server side is lost.

Comment: data is already saved, it's in the database. But after reloading the page the checkboxes aren't checked anymore.

Comment: Can you create an example in jsfidlle or plunkr? How do you get this data? Do you generate it as JavaScript in the page or get it through Ajax?